# Pulp: How to add/subtract decision variable outputs together

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp, mixed-integer-programming

I am working on a rail scheduling problem that moves product from a production plant to a storage facility to satisfy demand.

I am new to pulp so finding this difficult to understand why this isn't working, and unfortunately there is very little documentation on the subject.

**The problem**

There are three decision variables to monitor:

1. The availability/inventory of product at each plant - note each plant can manufacture different products.
2. Rail - how much to move of each product from each plant. Each train can move 8400 tons.
3. The inventory of each product at the storage facility.

Upon running the program, the rail decision variable works correctly i.e. the output is as expected, however the inventory at the plant and storage facility is not showing the amount removed and subsequently added by the rail.

Data & code below:

```
import pulp as pulp
import pandas as pd
import datetime

#rail capacity df from plant: no_trains_per_day max
rail_capacity_df_daily = {'ABC': {'capacity_per_day': 1, 'max': 19},
                          'DEF': {'capacity_per_day': 1, 'max': 50}}
rail_capacity_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(rail_capacity_df_daily ,orient='Index')

# facilities_df
facilities_inventory = {'BZL': {'current': 100000, 'max': 210000}, 
                        'AFM': {'current': 100000, 'max': 190000},
                        'PRE': {'current': 100000, 'max': 245000}}
facilities_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(facilities_inventory, orient='Index')


# plants_df
plant_df_inventory = {('ABC', 'PRE'): {'inventory': 196710, 'daily_production': 6000},
                      ('ABC', 'AFM'): {'inventory': 199910, 'daily_production': 5000},
                      ('DEF', 'BZL'): {'inventory': 127110, 'daily_production': 5000},
                      ('DEF', 'PRE'): {'inventory': 227100, 'daily_production': 6000}}  

plants_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(plant_df_inventory,orient='Index').rename_axis(['plant', 'product'])

# Sales demand

sales_demand = {'2020-04-24': {'AFM': 10000, 'PRE': 15000, 'BZL': 10000},
                '2020-04-25': {'AFM': 10000, 'PRE': 15000, 'BZL': 10000},
                '2020-04-26': {'AFM': 10000, 'PRE': 15000, 'BZL': 10000},
                '2020-04-27': {'AFM': 10000, 'PRE': 15000, 'BZL': 10000},
                '2020-04-28': {'AFM': 10000, 'PRE': 15000, 'BZL': 10000},
                '2020-04-29': {'AFM': 10000, 'PRE': 15000, 'BZL': 10000},}

sales_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sales_demand, orient='Index').rename_axis(['date'])

# Demand: Current Sales Demand
sales_demand = sales_df.to_dict(orient='index')

# PLANNING HORIZON PARAMS  
_current_date = pd.to_datetime(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d'))
planning_horizon_max = datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(4)
planning_horizon_max = pd.to_datetime(planning_horizon_max.strftime('%Y%m%d'))

# COMBINATION VARS
dates = [d.strftime('%F') for d in pd.date_range(_current_date,planning_horizon_max)]
plant_combinations = [(plant, product) for plant, product in plants_df.index]
products = [p for p in facilities_df.index] 
plants = ['ABC', 'DEF']

# Sales Demand: Grade Combinations by Date
demand_requirements = [(d, p) for d in dates for p in products]

# INVENTORY 
# Initial Storage Inventory
storage_inv = dict(zip(facilities_df.index, facilities_df['current']))

storage_max = dict(zip(facilities_df.index, facilities_df['max']))

# Initial Plant Inventory
plant_current_inventory = dict(zip(plants_df.index, plants_df.inventory))
plant_daily_production = dict(zip(plants_df.index, plants_df.daily_production))


# DECISION VARIABLES
# Plant facility vars
plant_inventory_vars = pulp.LpVariable.dicts(
    'Plant Inventory',
    ((date, plant, product) for date in dates for (plant, product) in plant_combinations),
    cat='Continuous',
    lowBound=0) 

# Storage Facility Vars
storage_facility_vars = pulp.LpVariable.dicts(
    'Storage Inventory',
    ((d, p) for d in dates for p in products),
    cat='Integer',
    lowBound=0)

# Total train capacity per plant dict
train_load_limit_daily = dict(zip(rail_capacity_df.index, 
                                  rail_capacity_df.capacity_per_day))

# Decision Vars: date, plant, product
train_consignment_variables = pulp.LpVariable.dicts(
    'Rail Loadings From plant',
    ((date, plant, product) for date in dates for (plant, product) in plant_combinations),
    cat='Continuous',
    lowBound=0) 


# OPTIMISATION

# Instantiate 
model = pulp.LpProblem('Rail Optimisation', pulp.LpMinimize)

solver = pulp.PULP_CBC_CMD()
solver.tmpDir = 'Users\CPrice2'

# Objective Function
model += pulp.lpSum(storage_max[product] 
    - storage_facility_vars[(date, product)] for (date, product) in storage_facility_vars), 'Minimise stockpile shortfalls'

    # PLANT INVENTORY
for date in dates:
  current_date = datetime.date.today().strftime('%F')
  date_t_minus_one = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d') - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
  date_t_minus_one = date_t_minus_one.strftime('%F')
  for plant, product in plant_combinations:
    if date == current_date:
      # Set current inventory
      model += plant_current_inventory[(plant, product)] - \
          train_consignment_variables[(date, plant, product)] == \
          plant_inventory_vars[(date, plant, product)] + \
          plant_daily_production[(plant, product)]
    else:
      # Get inventory from t-1
      model += plant_inventory_vars[(f'{date_t_minus_one}', plant, product)] - \
          train_consignment_variables[(date, plant, product)] == \
          plant_inventory_vars[(date, plant, product)] + \
          plant_daily_production[(plant, product)]

# Trains: Daily Rail Out Constraint 
for date in dates:
  for plant in plants:
    plant_product_combination = [tup for tup in plant_combinations if tup[0] == plant]
    variable_list = []
    for (plant_, product_) in plant_product_combination:
      variable = train_consignment_variables[(date, plant_, product_)]
      variable_list.append(variable)
    model += pulp.lpSum(var for var in variable_list) == train_load_limit_daily[plant] * 8400

# STORAGE FACILITY 
for date in dates:
  current_date = datetime.date.today().strftime('%F')
  date_t_minus_one = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d') - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
  date_t_minus_one = date_t_minus_one.strftime('%F')
  for plant, product in plant_combinations:
    if date == current_date:
      # Current Inv == current inventory + train in
      model += storage_inv[product] + \
          train_consignment_variables[(date, plant, product)] == \
          storage_facility_vars[(date, product)] - sales_demand[date][product] 
    else:
      model += storage_facility_vars[(f'{date_t_minus_one}', product)] + \
          train_consignment_variables[(date, plant, product)] == \
          storage_facility_vars[(date, product)] - sales_demand[date][product]

# Run solver
model.solve(solver)
pulp.LpStatus[model.status]

# Storage Out
storage_facility_out = []

for (date, product) in storage_facility_vars:
  var_out = {
      'Date': date,
      'Product': product,
      'Out Inventory': storage_facility_vars[(date, product)].varValue
  }
  storage_facility_out.append(var_out)

storage_facility_out_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(storage_facility_out).sort_values(['Date', 'Product'])
storage_facility_out_df.set_index(['Date', 'Product'], inplace=True)

# Rail Out
rail_optimisation_outputs = []

for date, plant, product in train_consignment_variables:
  var_output = {
      'Date': date,
      'Plant': plant,
      'Product': product,
      'Rail_Out': train_consignment_variables[(date, plant, product)].varValue
  }
  rail_optimisation_outputs.append(var_output)

output_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rail_optimisation_outputs).sort_values(['Date', 'Plant', 'Product'])
output_df.set_index(['Date', 'Plant', 'Product'], inplace=True)

# Production Plant Out
plant_stock_out = []

for date, plant, product in plant_inventory_vars:
  var_out = {
      'Date': date,
      'Plant': plant,
      'Product': product,
      'Out Inventory': plant_inventory_vars[(date, plant, product)].varValue
      }
  plant_stock_out.append(var_out)
plant_stock_out_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(plant_stock_out).sort_values(['Date', 'Product'])
plant_stock_out_df.set_index(['Date', 'Plant', 'Product'], inplace=True)
plant_stock_out_df
```

When I access the outputs of each decision variable:

```
train_consignment_vars.varValue = output ok.
```

For both plant and storage facilities I get the following:

storage_facility_vars.varValue = AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'value'. If I dont call .varValue, I simply get the dictionary values without accounting for the amount added/removed by rail.

Comment: you have the line `      storage_facility_vars[(date, product)] = plant_current_inv[product] 
` that is filling what once was a pulp variable with a value. This is changing your dictionary of variables into a dictionary with variables and, sometimes, floats

Comment: Thank you for your comment! this is intended to set the initial inventory. Is there a conventional way to setting it that doesn't adjust the type?

Comment: Two recommendations: 1) Share code which allows other people to reproduce your error - i.e. code which include a minimum/toy data wihtin the code itself and all required library imports. 2) Formulate your problem mathmetically before getting stuck into coding it up. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @kabdulla, fair point. I have added the data as a dataframe inc the imports. Re: the problem, this has been defined and formulated mathematically, however I find the Pulp documentation quite limited when attempting to replicate each expression.

Comment: This is better as the data is there - but if I run the code as you've pasted it I don't get the same result as you. In fact it doesn't run as you haven't imported `datetime`.  When I fix this I get the error that `facilities_df` has no index `'current`. If I don't get the same result as you its harder to demonstrate the fix.

Comment: Hi @kabdulla, thank you for your help and patience so far. I cant seem to find a way of uploading a csv of all the data - it looks as though SO doesn't allow this?

Comment: Don't upload a csv, hardcode a minimial toy amount of data into the problem itself - just enough to show the issue you are having. See [mcve] for more advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your code in the form of a reproducible example I can't be sure of all of the issues but here are a few:

1. After you've already added in your objective functions you seem to add further expressions which are not in the form of contraints for example:

`model += pulp.lpSum(plant_inventory_vars[(date, plant, product)]) - pulp.lpSum(train_consignment_variables[(date, plant, product)])`

This is not a constraint. The thing after `model +=` needs to take the form "A == B", or "A <= B", or "A >= B". Your expression does not.

There is another one here:

`model += pulp.lpSum(port_inventory_vars[(date, product)]) + pulp.lpSum(train_consignment_variables[(date, plant, product)] for plant, product in plant_combinations)`

2. As pointed out by @pchtsp you are overwritting some of your pulp variables:

`storage_facility_vars[(date, product)] = plant_current_inv[product]`

The general approach in linear programming is that you declare the variables, the objective to be optimized and then the constraints that exist. In PULP the objective and constraints are added to the problem using the `model +=` syntax. What you are doing here is taking a linear variable you've created and overwritting it with whatever is in `plant_current_inv[product'`. I think what you want to be doing instead is setting an equality constraint and adding that to the problem.

Comment: Thank you for this @kabdulla, I have now added everything - this should run and produce exactly the same outputs I am seeing hopefully!

Comment: Thanks for the updated code. When I run the code as you've got it now I get `NameError: name 'dates' is not defined`. You use the object `dates` before you declare it.  `plants_production_daily` is also not defined. I'd recommend running your code from a new/clean instance of python to check you definitely have everything declared as required.

Comment: Thank you @kabdulla - apologies I had to redefine a few things (like the dummy data) so these might have been defined and then subsequently added code with dependencies before them. Thank you once again.

Comment: Much better. You'll want to remove `solver.tmpDir = 'Users\CPrice2'`. Also my recommendation would be to avoid using `datetime.datetime.today()` in your example. If someone runs it tomorrow it will behave differently. Might make sense for your deployed code - but not your example here. Two more recomendations: 1. I would switch your date indexes to just be integer days from the start of the horizon - indexing by the date strings is messy and gets in the way. 2. The way you are handling tuples of indices at the moment is very cumbersome.

Comment: See https://www.coin-or.org/PuLP/CaseStudies/a_transportation_problem.html for an example that may be of some help.

Comment: Thank you for your help @kabdulla. Yes I did see this example, however unlike in my case it does not keep track of physical tons sadly. Can I ask whether the code is returning the correct tonnage being moved when it runs for you please?